# How to prevent SMS message truncation if > 160 chars, from a .NET app

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sms, sendgrid

When my .NET app sends a text message by email message, via Sendgrid, to the email address of an SMS device, like an iPhone, if message is > 160 characters, then only the characters up to 160 arrive.

I've tried programmatically breaking up and sending the >160 message in chunks that are <= 160, but they don't arrive in predictable order.

Comment: Good luck, you do not have control over the email; when it sends email and if it even does send. You need an API (like Nexmo) to do this in which you can call.  Currently theres no guarantee the user will get these messages in order as you are experiencing.Also you said you can do them in chunks, but as mentioned its not guaranteed to send in order.

Comment: Back in the days, I would receive message that would start with a page number / max page.   "1/10 some text" ... that way I could read the message properly.

Comment: Those are called multi-part messages or concatenated messages @the_lotus. The way concatenation works in GSM and UMTS networks is specified in SMS Point to Point specification. AFAIK you cant do this through email. Not all networks support this though. When they dont they are seperate messages. Look into UDH that deal with headers...

Comment: Send a regular email message.

Comment: @Codexer He could always do this process himself. Splitting the message and adding the page number at the beginning. But a proper solution is still the best way to go.